# VBA macro crashing Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that I use to maintain tests for an automated test application written with Selenium WebDriver. The spreadsheet has 6 ActiveX buttons that Upload (to a database), Import (from another sheet), Clear All Sheets, Export (to another sheet), Merge (two sheets), and Restore (a test suite from the database). My problem seem to stem from the macro that runs when the Import button is selected

The macro takes two sheets, source and destination, clears the destination sheet and copies the cells and data from the source workbook to the corresponding sheet in the destination workbook. From there, it can either be uploaded to the database or run from the sheet by the testing app

A couple weeks ago when selecting the Import button Excel crashed. I looked on the web and found a solution that worked. It involved disabling all macros, shutting down trust documents and trusted locations, recompiling, and reopening the workbook. This worked for a couple weeks until the same thing happened again this past weekend and the fix did not work anymore.

Here is the code I have:

```
numSheets = wrkBook.Sheets.Count

appName = wrkSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value

bkPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")

If bkPath <> "False" Then

    Call Clear_All(wrkBook, wrkSheet)

    'get the number of sheets in the source workbook
    destCnt = wrkBook.Sheets.Count

    Set importBook = Workbooks.Open(bkPath)
    For a = 1 To destCnt
        thsShtName = wrkBook.Worksheets(a).Name
        'activate the source workbook
        importBook.Activate

        'get the numer of sheets in the source workbook
        srcCnt = importBook.Sheets.Count

        'loop through each sheet checking title
        For b = 1 To srcCnt
            'get the name of the 'a' sheet
            **srcSheetName = importBook.Worksheets(b).Name**

            'do more stuff with the source sheet
        Next b
Next a
End If
```

The code is crashing on the following line
    srcSheetName = importBook.Worksheets(b).Name

Here are a few things that I have noticed. Once the importBook variable is set, I cannot expand the variable in a watch window even if the code has not reached the offending line. However, the macro will successfully get the srcCount (number of sheet on the source sheet). Once the macro gets to the offending line it crashes consistently with a message stating simply that Excel has encountered an error and needs to close . No information, Excel closes, and sometimes restarts to a blank workbook

Comment: Maybe one of the sheets in the file that you are trying to open is corrupt? What is the value of `b` at the time of error?

Comment: I'm investigating the fact that the source sheet might corrupt by saving one of the others, clearing the saved sheet, and copying all the data from the "corrupt" sheet one by one


b = 1 (as expected) when it hits the line it fails on

Comment: Put a break on that line and then in the immediate window type `?importBook.Name` and similarly check for `?importBook.Sheets(1).Name`

Comment: Are all of your **Sheets** Worksheeets or are some of them **Charts** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...I figured this out myself after heeding Siddarth Rout's suggestion about a corrupt spreadsheet. I took the steps that I described above

So here's what I did.

I copied one of the other spreadsheets and cleared it.  As soon as I ran the Import macro, it passed through the line where it was failing before, so a corruption seems to have been the issue. I then stepped through the original code and rewrote the Import macro to simplify the code in it. It now seems to be working just fine

Thanks for the suggestions!!